# Access Violation Upon Thread Completion

Tags: multithreading, pointers, multidimensional-array

Here is the setup.
I create a global variable `GLfloat ***terrainMap;` 
Next, in a main thread function, I initialize it as

```
    terrainMap = new GLfloat**[size+1];
for(int i = 0; i < size+1; i++)
{
terrainMap[i] = new GLfloat*[size+1];
for(int j = 0; j < size+1; j++)
{
  terrainMap[i][j] = new GLfloat[4];
}
}
```

I then precede to pass this into two objects so they can write and read the original data.

```
current.AddObject(new Terrain(1,0.5f,terrainMap));
current.AddObject(new Grass(2,terrainMap));

Terrain::Terrain(int tag1,float smoothnessInclination1,GLfloat ***terrainMap1){
terrainMap= terrainMap1;

Grass::Grass(int tag1,GLfloat ***terrainMap1){
terrainMapG=terrainMap1;
```

I felt pretty confidant at this point as the writing of the data in a different thread

```
terrainMap[i][c][0] = ((hold.x+1)/2.0f)*255;
terrainMap[i][c][1] = ((hold.y+1)/2.0f)*255;
terrainMap[i][c][2] = ((hold.z+1)/2.0f)*255;
terrainMap[i][c][3] = vertexData[(i*(size+1))+(c)].XYZW[1];
```

and the reading of the data in the different thread

```
+terrainMapG[i][c][3]
```

worked well. 
However, when the thread itself ended. An access violation occurred and I have no idea how.

This is the detached thread

```
void LoadObjects(){
for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;i != current.storage.size();i++){
    current.storage.at(i)->Load();
}
runLoad=false;
}
```

I know I am not reading and writing data at the same time, so what could it be?

EDIT:
After decreasing the value of size from 1000 to 100, a new error is thrown. `Unhandled exception at 0x0000000076EE40F2 (ntdll.dll) in Procedural Terrain.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x0000000076F5B450).` instead of the original `Unhandled exception at 0x00000000694E0760 (nvoglv64.dll) in Procedural Terrain.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000002770258.`

In addition, right before the error with size=100, the program stops with the error that it has hit a breakpoint in realloc.c where I do not have a breakpoint set at the code

```
pvReturn = NULL;
        if (newsize <= _HEAP_MAXREQ)
        {
            if (newsize == 0)
                newsize = 1;
            pvReturn = HeapReAlloc(_crtheap, 0, pBlock, newsize);
        }
        else
        {
            _callnewh(newsize);
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        }
```

Comment: Which thread deallocates the data? Which one terminates first?

Comment: The main thread deallocates the data far after the "loader" thread terminates. It is so far into the future of the program, as the data is used consistently, that It should not affect the loader thread.

Comment: there's something confusing about your code: there are `terrainMap` and `terrainMapG`, yet you state at the beginning that you create a global, which I understand as a single global.

Comment: you could try using a memory leak detector like valgrind.

Comment: The global variable is only global only to the main thread and the loader thread. I guess then it is not strictly global because no other class files include the main thread. `terrainMap` in the Terrain Class should be labeled `terrainMapT` to prevent confusion. They are instances pointing to the original `terrainMap` as they can not access the original itself.

Comment: at this point I don't think I can find the problem without more code. As I said earlier, you should try valgrind, or some similar software to analyse the memory usage.

Comment: I appreciate the effort!

Comment: you also may want to check that all array accesses are within their bounds, ie. `c` and `i` are always `>=0` and `<size+1` for `terrainMap`. Likewise for `.vertexData`.

Comment: One last point: try replaceling the for loop in the detached thread by a loop on an iterator: `for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=current.storage.begin(); it != currenr.storage.end(); it++) it->Load();` .

Comment: All accesses are valid as with no thread and no creation of the 3D pointer (no loading system), everything works perfectly. Sadly, the iterator you gave does not change the problem.

Comment: Well, looking at the problem from a different angle... Is this a good solution to sharing the `terrainMap` data between two classes that are created dynamically?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't pay attention to that fact: are you trying to delete the array in each destructor? There's a RAII principle violation there anyway.

Comment: No I am not trying to delete the array at any point in the program.

Comment: Well then there's no issue with the RAII principle.

Comment: I updated the question with an interesting find.

Comment: instead of using `GLfloat *** terrainMap;` I think you should use something like `ArrayList<GLfloat> ** terrainMap;` which is an array that can be accessed concurrently by different threads and is thread-safe